# How to configure many to many relation in query not to show duplicate lines?

Tags: ms-access-2010, rdbms

I have 2 tables, one for students and other for classes.
Each class can have many students and one student can learn in 2 classes max.
I've created a third table to allow many to many relationship, then I created a query
that present "student name" and "class".

```
student name    Class
   john       C
   anri       B
   john       A
```

instead of showing same student(john) in 2 lines, I wish to add a class column to the query
in such way it will show student name then the 2 classes related to him.

```
student name    Class   Class
       john       C       A
       anri       B       -
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Can we assume you never record more than 2 classes per student?  And if there is someone in the students table for whom you have not yet recorded any classes, should that student be included in the query result set?

Comment: max is 2 classes, the classless student should show but with no classes